# Deploy third party updates with SCUP and WSUS without SCCM

Tags: wsus

We are trying to install SCUP on a Windows Server 2016 to deploy third party (non Microsoft) updates on a WSUS server.
The publishing of SCUP is ok and WSUS doesn't show the SCUP update files.

In the WSUS console, the upstream server shows the number of SCUP updates. Why does WSUS not show the SCUP updates?